# MYSQL - How can we use a table which was locked with "LOCK TABLES" statement inside a CTE (common table expression)?

Tags: mysql, locking, common-table-expression

I have a table named order_bd.
I locked it using `lock tables order_bd write;`.
Now I am trying to refer to that table inside a CTE:

```
with tmp as (select * from order_bd where DATANO = '20277207' and RECNO = '641605567' )
select *
from tmp
WHERE DATAKB = (SELECT MIN(DATAKB) FROM TMP);
```

Executing that statement throws an error:

> [1100] Table 'order_bd' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

So what is the proper way to refer to a table which was locked using `LOCK TABLES` inside a CTE?

Comment: You read from this table in CTE - hence you must lock this table for READ.

Comment: @Akina I just tried and it produced the same error. I think that a WRITE lock has a higher priority than a READ lock, so it does not really matter in this situation.

Comment: Better to use transactions, if needed, rather than explicit locking table. `LOCK TABLES` is something you should very rarely need if ever.